# Rescanning the 'defined' operator after macro expansion: should it work?

Tags: c, macros, doxygen, c-preprocessor

Consider

```
#define FOOBAR (defined(FOO) || defined(BAR))

#if FOOBAR
/* Do stuff. */
#endif
```

Should this work? I'm asking because apparently my compilers have no problem with it, but the doxygen internal preprocessor thinks there is a syntax error with the `#if`. I know I could work around this with

```
#if defined(FOO) || defined(BAR)
#define FOOBAR 1
#endif
#if FOOBAR
/* Do stuff. */
#endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C99 spec:

> **6.10.1.3**
>
> Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become
> the controlling constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified
> by the defined unary operator), just as in normal text. If the token defined is
> generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the defined unary operator
> does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is
> undefined.

So if you use a macro that expands to `defined` as you have done, the result is undefined.

As with most undefined things in the C spec, its undefined because implementations prior to the standard handled it differently.

Comment: +1, ... or the committee judged it too much of a burden for a compiler implementor to take care of that particular error condition

Comment: from the GCC Preprocessor manual: `If the defined operator appears as a result of a macro expansion, the C standard says the behavior is undefined. GNU cpp treats it as a genuine defined operator and evaluates it normally. It will warn wherever your code uses this feature if you use the command-line option `-pedantic', since other compilers may handle it differently.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a compiler-specific question. As long as you're just using this compiler, just try it out - put some code in the `/*do stuff*/` part, and see whether or not the code is compiled.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of deducing "how it must work" from "how does it work with my particular compilers." This would constitute *programming by experimentation*, which I think is not good engineering. Since C and preprocessor behaviour is specified in an international Standard, that's where we should look for *definitive* answers.